# My freezer is not freezing

Tags: refrigerator

If the freezer in my refrigerator is not freezing, should I turn the unit off?  The compressor is running and the fan is also.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Why would you do that, or why do you think it would be necessary?

Comment: You should probably make sure the fan is working first and that there is not a lot of ice buildup in the bottom that would stop the freezer from working , lots of other things could be the cause but with the info provided this would be my first step.

Comment: Is there airflow from the vents? It sounds like Ed's idea might nail it. And further, is the door seal good? Yes, you should turn it off if it is not doing its job. Prepare for water drainage if yours has this, it might be related to why it isnt working. Put the items inside in a new location. If you get the unit working again, avoid blocking the air vents, and ensure the door is sealing tight.